# Error al modificar la URL The payload is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, url

Tengo un link encriptado :

```
<a href="{{ route('BLC',Crypt::encrypt($F->idF))}}" target="_blank"> Holi o_o/ </a>
```

paso atrevas de mi ruta normal mente :

```
Route::get('/BLC/{idF}', 'ControllerWizard@BLC')->name('BLC');
Route::post('/BLC/{idF}', 'ControllerWizard@BLC')->name('BLC');
```

y des encripto en mi controlador :

```
    public function BLC($id)
    {
$id =  Crypt::decrypt($id);
$F = F::findOrFail($id);

return view('BLC', compact('F'));
    }
```

todo bien al mostrar la pagina y la URL pero al tomarla cambiar algun parametro y entrar a este portal URL en lugar de salir la pagina de error de Laravel que tiene por defecto sale un error :

```
Illuminate \ Contracts \ Encryption \ DecryptException
The payload is invalid.
```

Como puedo solucionarlo ? :(

Answer (score 6):

Es simple tienes el nombre de tu ruta repetida:

```
Route::get('/BLC/{idF}', 'ControllerWizard@BLC')->name('BLC');
Route::post('/BLC/{idF}', 'ControllerWizard@BLC')->name('BLC');
```

deberías de cambiar uno de ellos para que no exista este conflicto:

```
Route::get('/BLC/{idF}', 'ControllerWizard@BLC')->name('BLC.get');
Route::post('/BLC/{idF}', 'ControllerWizard@BLC')->name('BLC.post');
```

y los llamas respectivamente en tus vistas, en tu caso el get:

```
<a href="{{ route('BLC.get',Crypt::encrypt($F->idF))}}" target="_blank"> Holi o_o/ </a>
```

con eso tu problema debería de ser eliminado.

Puede que sea error de la cookie "XDEBUG_SESSION", edita el archivo `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies` de la siguiente manera:

```
protected $except = [
    'XDEBUG_SESSION'
];
```

Comment: muchas gracias! , se ve y nota que es mejor asi y a  resuelto proablemente un futuro problema sin considerar que tiene mejor presentación, pero mi problema persiste cambio un poco la URL muestra error y no la pagina por defecto de error :(

Comment: @clausvargas, edite la respuesta quiza esta otra opcion te funcione

Comment: sigue apareciendo el error T^T , creo que tartare de buscar una opción donde no aparezca el id , en lugar de que salga encriptado o algo

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException; // agregas este erchivo al controlador   

public function ticket($ticket){ // tu funcion

    try {
       $ticket =decrypt($ticket); //desencriptar tu variable
     }catch (DecryptException $e) {
        return view('errors.500');// vista de error
    }
}
```

function

Comment: Hola! Gracias por aportar y tratar de resolver la pregunta. Procura siempre indicar por qué el código que pones resuelve el problema, así como un texto breve indicando cómo usarlo. Recuerda que puedes editar tus preguntas y respuestas siempre, usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo la respuesta